# How could I do this integral?

Tags: integration, matrices

> Suppose $\alpha, F, M, N: n \times n$
>
> $\alpha^T = \alpha$, $M^T = M$
>
> eig(F)< 0
>
> $$
> \int_0^{\infty} \left(e^{Ft} \right)^T \left[2 \alpha - (N^T M + MN )t \right]e^{Ft} \, dt
> $$

I met a problem like the picture shows. M, alpha are symmetric, eigenvalue of F are all negative.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: what is $T$ in the expression $(N^T M + MN )T$ ? Is it a typo?

Comment: T means transpose!

Answer (score 0):

If $F$ is diagonizable, you can write $F=A^{-1} D A$ for some $A,D$ and $D$ diagonal.
Then you have to solve

$I=\int_0^{\infty} A^Te^{Dt} A^{-T} \left[2 \alpha - (N^T M + MN )t \right]A^{-1}e^{Dt}A \, dt$

To simplify notation, call

$P=A^{-T}\alpha A^{-1}, Q=A^{-T}(N^T M + MN ) A^{-1}$

and write $I=A^{T}[\int_0^{\infty} \left(e^{Dt} \right) \left[2 P - Q t \right]A^{-1}e^{Dt} \, dt]A$

The integral $I_1=2\int_0^{\infty} \left(e^{Dt} \right)  Pe^{Dt} \, dt $ can be solved in the index form $I^{ij}_1= 2\int_0^{\infty} e^{D^{ii}t}   P^{ij}e^{D^{jj}t} \, dt$

And similarly for $I_2= [\int_0^{\infty} \left(e^{Dt} \right) \left[Q t \right]A^{-1}e^{Dt} \, dt]$

with the final solution given by $I=A^{T} [I_1-I_2]A$